# Right syntax for multiple condition sql update nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Hi everyone so I want to use with update two conditions with where, AND.

I have tried that :

```
con.query('UPDATE utilisateursinvitation SET  numgroup = ?, WHERE grandtokenuser = ? , nomwork = ?', [ numgroup, nulyutulisateur, nomwork], function (error, results, fields) {
```

And that :

```
  con.query('UPDATE utilisateursinvitation SET  numgroup = ?, WHERE grandtokenuser = ? AND nomwork = ?', [ numgroup, nulyutulisateur, nomwork], function (error, results, fields) {
```

But nothing work because I don't know the right syntax. Can you help me ?

Comment: Get rid of the comma before `WHERE`.

Comment: Use `AND` between conditions in `WHERE`.

Comment: Syntax is explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Comment: @Barmar I think that your two comments qualify as an answer for this :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think this qualifies for closing as a typo, but I'm out of votes.

Comment: @Barmar fair enough. Let me help with another one.